# Background image stretched to the browser width & repeating-Y & opaque?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following style to create an opaque background image (for the whole page) which stretches to fit the browser width. Am I able to also make the image repeat vertically?

I have tried `background-repeat: repeat-y;` but it does not work how I need it to.

#### CSS

```
html:after {
  content : "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url('backdrop.png'); 
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity : 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: the repeat y code is correct -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp do you need the width and height to be 100%?

Comment: If I take out "height: 100%;" I don't get any background image at all

Comment: I have never seen this added to html. have you tried it on the body tag?

Comment: On the body tag it comes out the same as on the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it on html instead (not in :after) .

```
html {
  background: url("backdrop.png") left top repeat-y;
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with the following code:

```
html{
 content : "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-image: url('backdrop.png'); 
 background-size: cover;
 opacity : 0.2;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

i.e. remove after and width height 100% and add the repeat-y

Comment: I removed my style and pasted yours in but I don't get any background image at all (Firefox).

Comment: I see it big as the screen :| If I remove the **background-size: cover;** I get a repeated image in the y axis only, so maybe you can try that.